# One Client just listening after a few messages: Client Server Chat with ArrayList sockets outputstreamwriter

Tags: multithreading, sockets, server, chat, outputstream

i have got a problem with my broadcast method. I did a chat with server and clients. Each client runs one thread and has a own socket for the output stream At the beginning all works fine but after a few messages only one client can send while the other is only receiving the messages..?! i don't know why Someone an idea? At the beginning both can send and receive..
i can't close the outputstream because then i get a nullpointerexception but maybe that is the mistake?
Thankful for every help!

Server:

```
public static void broadcastJSON(JSONObject jsonObject, ArrayList<Socket> socketList)throws IOException{

        OutputStreamWriter out = null;
        for(int i=0; i<socketList.size(); i++){
            out=new OutputStreamWriter(socketList.get(i).getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            out.write(jsonObject.toString() + "\n");
            out.flush();
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
public JSONObject receiveJSON()throws IOException{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Client.socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String obje = in.readLine();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(obje);
        return jsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're losing data read-ahead by the `BufferedReader.` Don't create new streams/readers/writers per message. Use the same ones for the life of the socket.

Comment: okay i will try that thank you! i thought about it before. in the received message it should be possible, but how can i do it in the broadcast method when i have to stream out for every particular socket in the socketList.. Thanks for your reply!